# AWS API Gateway to forward requests to an HTTPS server with a private certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, configuration, certificate

Here's my scenario: I am trying to set up the AWS API Gateway so that all calls to the API Gateway endpoints will be forwarded to an Nginx HTTPS server behind it:

```
          HTTPS                HTTPS                    HTTPS                plain HTTP
[Client] ------> {{Internet}} -----> [AWS API Gateway] -----> [HTTPS server] ----------> [Internal web services]
```

Only the HTTPS server can access the internal web services inside a private network. The HTTPS server itself is publicly accessible on the Internet, as is the AWS API Gateway.

Now, the SSL certificate I installed on the HTTPS server is a private one, signed by a private CA I created.

[See my AWS API Gateway config here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mny83.png)

When the AWS API Gateway tries to forward an HTTPS request to the HTTPS server, via an HTTPS endpoint URL pointing to the server, the AWS API Gateway gets an error:

```
"Execution failed due to configuration error: General SSLEngine problem"
```

Perhaps this is because the AWS API Gateway does not recognize my private CA. If so, how do I import my private CA to the AWS API Gateway for this usage?

Edit: My intent here is that the AWS API Gateway will have to authenticate to the HTTPS server using the API Gateway's client certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use self-signed certificates with API Gateway. If your API Gateway is only meant to be speaking to your server then take a look at using [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) on your local EC2 instance.

Alternatively if you want to add more security, you could perform the following actions.

- Migrate the EC2 instance into a private subnet.
- Either import or create a new certificate via ACM.
- Create an internal network load balancer with a TLS listener, using the certificate you've got setup in ACM.
- Create a [VPCLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) so that your API Gateway can access your internal NLB.